# How can i prevent my app stopped when phone Reboot in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I was working on flutter app and my app mainly works in background so , what I want is to run my app continuously without stopping when the phone is rebooted, or at any means my app should run in background forever.
so, is there any mechanism in flutter to do This?

Answer (score 0):

this can only be done on Android side on IOS when user closes the app its process will be killed shortly after (we are talking seconds or minutes).

on Android you can achieve this by using a `ForegroundService` plugin like [android_long_task](https://pub.dev/packages/android_long_task)

Comment: ok, but can't we do or achieve this using accessibility service or device administration services ?